Surjective on open sets implies surjective on stalks
Suppose $\varphi: \mathscr{F} \to \mathscr{G}$ is a morphism of sheaves on $X.$ I would like to show that if the maps $\varphi(U): \mathscr{F}(U) \to \mathscr{G}(U)$ are surjective for all open sets $U\subseteq X$ then the maps $\varphi_x : \mathscr{F}_x \to \mathscr{G}_x$ are surjective for all $x \in X.$
My current progress is as follows: Since $$\mathscr{F}_x := \left(\coprod_{U \text{ open nbhd of }x}\mathscr{F}(U)/\sim\right)$$ and $\varphi(U)$ is surjective for all $U,$ it is enough to show $$\coprod\varphi(\mathscr{F}(U))/\sim \,\stackrel{?}= \varphi\left(\coprod\mathscr{F}(U)\right)/ \sim.$$
I am unsure how to prove the equality.

Pick an element of the stalk, pick a representative, ... I'll let you finish.

@BenSteffan Do I need to use the sheaf properties or does this actually hold for presheaves?

It holds for presheaves as well.

Pick an element $t \in \mathscr{G}_x.$ By definition, there exists an open neighbourhood $U \subseteq X$ of $x$  and a section $\tilde{t} \in \mathscr{G}(U)$ such that $t = [(U,\tilde{t})].$ From the surjectivity of $\varphi(U)$, we have a section $\tilde{s} \in \mathscr{F}(U)$ such that $\varphi(U)(\tilde{s}) = \tilde{t}.$ Set $s:=[(U,\tilde{s})].$ We now see that $$\varphi_x(s) = \varphi([(U,\tilde{s})]) = [(U,\varphi(U)(\tilde{s}))] = [(U,\tilde{t})]=t.$$ Which proves the claim.
